# If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.(its not a typo but caused by circular import)

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

This is very unusual . The code was running fine but all of sudden this error appeared :

```
     Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns  
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner       
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper      
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check   
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks, 
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)      
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', []) 
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__      
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 596, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'backend.urls' 
does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

My backend.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('base.urls')),
]
```

My base.urls :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getRoutes, name='getRoutes'),
]
```

My base/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .products import products

# Create your views here.


def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
        '/api/products/',
        '/api/products/create/',

        '/api/products/upload',

        '/api/products/<id>/reviews/',

        '/api/products/top/',
        '/api/products/<id>/',

        '/api/products/delete/<id>',
        '/api/products/<update>/<id>/',
    ]
    return JsonResponse(routes, safe=False)
```

I am using django for quite long now never seen this error the exact code was running fine but as I define second func in views the error occurred I remove that func but error doesnt go . I have tried all answer please help

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: hi Willem I have posted the traceback please check . I think it's IDE issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the same problems as you.

I had a views.py file where I tried to import form with all correct.

And it gave me the following error:

> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 600, in
> url_patterns
> iter(patterns) TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64,
> in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
> line 118, in inner_run
> self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
> 423, in check
> databases=databases,   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line
> 76, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line
> 13, in check_url_config
> return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23,
> in check_resolver
> return check_method()   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in
> check
> for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48,
> in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 607, in
> url_patterns
> raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included
> URLconf 'projectWS.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it.
> If you see valid patterns  in the file then the issue is probably
> caused by a circular import.

All was correct in the urlpatterns, etc ... So I didn't understand why this occured.

Finally the error was because in my views.py, I put

```
from forms import ConversionForm
```

instead of

```
from .forms import ConversionForm
```

So, it can be a problem of import